# Exception analysis tool for C++

Tags: c++, exception, code-analysis

I've been looking for a tool to extract exception information from a C++ program. The most wanted feature I'm looking for: I want to know all the exceptions that can be thrown from a function (which would include all the function that is called from that function recursively).

I've always thought that documenting errors and exceptions in particular is very hard (and takes a lot of effort to keep up to date). But if there is some way to automate that, it would be very helpful.

A tool for windows and Visual Studio would be preferred but not necessary, I could always work around that.

Answer (score 7):

[PC-Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/) claims to do static exception analysis of C++ code.
[Coverity](http://www.coverity.com/) is another static C++ code analysis tool that apparently informs you of unhandled exceptions.
[AQtime](http://www.automatedqa.com/products/aqtime/index.asp) claims to have exception tracing as part of its code analysis. Plus, they advertise Visual Studio integration.
[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111007220353/http://testingfaqs.org/t-static.html) is a list of several static code analysis tools.

Answer (score 6):

**DISCLAIMER:** Working on this tool is my day job.

Its hard for me to write this without it looking like a sales pitch, so I apologise in advance.

As well as other analysis, [QA C++](http://www.programmingresearch.com/QACPP_MAIN.html) outputs the list of types that are thrown from the body of functions and the call tree.  I believe that this would be all the information that you require.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I've just talked to them and I'm getting a demo. It looks good on paper, I really hope its can handle what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

EDoC++ (http://edoc.sourceforge.net) is another alternative.