# Forcing C++ compilers to check for exception handling

Tags: c++, exception

I was wondering if there is some compiler parameter, preferably in gcc (g++) which treats the lack of try/catch blocks as errors. This is the standard behavior in java and I was alway fond of it.

Comment: Nope, and it's basically not possible given the design of the standard, since it's not possible at compile time to know exactly what functions are going to be called.

Comment: Locate main function. Put everything in a try-catch block. No error. :) (I wonder what happens if exceptions are thrown during the construction of globals?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since checked exceptions in Java rely on the `throw` signature, you can read why you will not want to use `throw` function signatures in C++ in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature-c) on SO.

Answer (score 1):

Well, using exception specifications is generally a bad idea: http://cplusplus.co.il/2009/10/06/exception-specifications/

And if not using these, the compiler basically has no way of knowing which exception may be thrown, so there's no way to do that.

What you could do, is provide your own implementation of std::terminate (by invoking std::set_terminate()) and handle uncaught exceptions there.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you *can* do in C++ with exceptions is use exception specifications on your functions. That doesn't actively *prevent* non-listed exceptions from being thrown from that function, but it makes them errors (and maps them all to the predefined `unexpected()`.

So `int f() throw ();` is C++ for "treat any exception being raised from function f as an error".

Comment: Probably worth noting that it's "treat as _runtime_ error". A C++ compiler is still _required_ to compile `void foo() throw() { throw 42; }`.