# LoadLibrary Problem on Win7 (64-bit)

Tags: c++

I developed MFC Regular DLL "Static Linked" using vs2005. when compiled it as 32-bit DLL

I can load it using "LoadLibrary" from my machine or from any other machine.

but when compile it as 64-bit DLL I can only load it from my machine.

I review my code and found global object declared.

```
MyClass myObj;
```

when I comment this object..I can load DLL and use it from diffrent machine.but when any

global object found...I can't load my DLL from diffrenet machine.

anyone can help me?

Comment: Are other machines 64 bit compatible ?

Comment: yes..it Win7 64-bit also

Comment: does your DLL have any dependencies? Use depends.exe from sysinternals

Comment: What exactly happens when you try to load it???

Comment: No.. it doesn't have any dependencies . @kichik: Handle of "LoadLibrary" return NULL..when I try to use "GetLastError" it return number like "-529697949"

Answer (score 2):

> when I try to use "GetLastError" it return number like "-529697949"

The error code is 0xe06d7363, the last 3 hex digits spell "MSC".  That's the exception code for a C++ exception in Microsoft's compiler.

Your code is bombing on a uncaught C++ exception, probably thrown in DllMain().  You'll need a debugger if you can't reverse-engineer it from this hint.

Comment: can You explain how I can do that?

Comment: Well, I can only guess.  Go by what the debugger tells you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..but at other machines I can't install VS2005 IDE to debug my DLL  ... after I installed  64bit Visual C++ 2005 redistibutable my exe that load DLL produce exception says "Debug Error! This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in a unusual way

(Press Retry to debug the application)
"

Answer (score 0):

Does the target machine have the 64bit Visual C++ 2005 redistibutable installed? It's possible they have the 32 bit version installed from other application but that the 64 bit one has never been installed?

See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=90548130-4468-4bbc-9673-d6acabd5d13b

Comment: I install it now..and the problem still exist

Answer (score 0):

The uncaught C++ exception can also be thrown while the global/static objects of your dll are created/allocated/initialized (which is part of DllMain). So there is a good chance that somewhere in the code a valid throw statement is responsible for this behaviour (rather than some compiler/architecture/platform bug; maybe its just a define that is x64 specific?).

To find that nasty little *#!!:

- Compile all your code with debug information (/DEBUG)
- Turn on the Symbol Server (Debug/Options/Debugging/Symbols/Symbol file (.pdb) locations: [x] Microsoft Symbol Servers)
- Turn on all Break on Exceptions (Debug/Exceptions.../ Tick all [] in the "Thrown" column)
- Start Debugging and you will eventually find the correct place.

Due to the missing enforced "throws" statement like e.g. in Java (in c++ its optional and pretty useless; see [Throw keyword in function's signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature-c) ), the try/catch/throw system is hardly usable to create robust and maintainable code; its almost like hiding random gotos everywhere.