# A class using another class's method c++

Tags: c++, class, try-catch

I have two classes, `A`, and `B`.  They are declared thusly:

```
class A
{
    public: void function() throw (exception);
};

class B
{
    public: void function();
};
```

`B::function` calls `A::function`.  Inside `B::function`, I want to suppress the exception that `A::function` sometimes throws, and continue execution afterwards.  How do I do this?

Comment: Well, you can just wrap every call to a method from `A` with `try { } catch (...) {}` to swallow the exception.  That will work, but it's generally a bad idea to ignore exceptions.

Comment: Can you try to post real code? What you posted will not compile since `A::function` will be private and `B` isn't a `friend` of `A`.

Comment: Throw in the function signature is a bad practice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature-c), and throwing things besides std::exceptions is a bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

You can drop all exceptions using `try { .. } catch ( ... ) { }`:

```
void ClassB::doSomething()
{
    try {
        classAObject.doSomethingWhichMayThrow();
    } catch ( ... ) {
    }
}
```

Please note that this may have moral implications. You should be ready to explain (at least in a comment of the code) why swallowing exceptions at this point is acceptable.

Comment: I still have the problem. I write an example to show.
http://codepad.org/4cMBEYHg
http://codepad.org/d5Epig9R
http://codepad.org/Ix1zjrIK
http://codepad.org/LWlFPjni

when I'm compiling, it stops.