# Exceptions in the constructor c++

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

so I have a problem with this:

```
class Exception{
    private : string message;
    public : 
    Exception();
    Exception(string str);
    string what();

};
class Something{
public : Something(int m) throw(Exception);
....}
```

and in the cpp file:

```
Exception::Exception()
    {
        message="cant divide by 0";
    }
    Exception::Exception(string str)
    {
        message = str;
    }
    Exception:string what()
    {
        return message;
    }
```

and then i tried to use it inside some constructor

```
Something::Something(int m) throw(Exception)
    {
        if (m==0) 
        {
            throw Exception();
        }
     };
```

and in the main

```
...
catch(Exception obj){
    cout<<obj.what();
```

}

and it shows "Exception" does not name a type and 'obj' wasnt declared and I wonder why.

Comment: Your `Exception` must inherit from `std::exception` to be usable in try/catch...

Comment: @c650 No, Exception is perfectly fine the way it is.

Comment: Are you including you exception header file in your main cpp file?

Comment: yeah, i included everything okay, just didnt post the whole code here @1201ProgramAlarm

Comment: `Something(int m) throw(Exception)`? That looks more like Java than c++.

Comment: @CraigYoung It's legal C++ (though deprecated by `noexcept`).

Comment: `Exception:string what()` should be `string Exception::what()`

Answer (score 0):

The Exception class may be incomplete.

It doesn't look to me like Exception::what() is defined correctly.

Try...

```
string Exception::what()
{
    return message;
}
```

Also, as others have mentioned, in c++ you don't have to define what a function throws like in java. See this question for more details...

[Throw keyword in function's signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055387/throw-keyword-in-functions-signature)

```
Something::Something(int m)
{
    if (m==0) 
    {
        throw Exception();
    }
};
```

Also typically I'd catch a reference to the thrown exception unless it is a primitive type. This will avoid making a copy of the exception.

Try...

```
...
catch(const Exception& obj) {
    cout << obj.what();
}
```

Comment: Should probably catch by const-reference, but since exception objects should be immutable anyway, I guess it doesn't matter much.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @CodyGray, I've updated above. Better late than never I guess.