# Is there any use for C++ throw decoration?

Tags: c++, exception

I've started using C++ exceptions in a uniform manner, and now I'd like the compiler (g++) to check that there are no "exception leaks". The `throw` decoration should do this, like `const` does for constness of class methods.

Well, it doesn't.

Using `throw` is still documentary, but may even be dangerously misleading if others think a function cannot throw other exceptions than those listed in its documentation.

Can g++ somehow be persuaded to be more strict on its throw-checking, i.e. really making sure a function decorated as `throw()` will never-ever throw anything.

Edit:
Found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88573/should-i-use-an-exception-specifier-in-c) handling the subject widely.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037575/why-arent-exceptions-in-c-checked-by-the-compiler

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't check compile-time, but a conforming compiler should ensure it at run-time.

If a function throws anything outside of its throw-declaration, the C++ run-time should call std::unexpected, if I recall correctly.

Comment: That's my understanding too. Why you'd want it to do so I've no idea. I personally find `GetFoo() // throws(std::runtime_error)` much more useful than the uncommented equivalent - just as a hint to consumers of my code.

Comment: Correct. The practical problem for compile-time checking is that most existing C++ code has no throw specification.

Comment: Visual C++ 2008 doesn't support this part of standard.

Comment: @Kirill: Interesting, I didn't know that.

Comment: Update: as far as I have seen, VS 2012 still doesn't support that part of the standard.

Answer (score 8):

I would also recommend to look at [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm) essay about the exception specifications. It points out the problems of this C++ feature like:

- It's a shadow type system
- The compiler checks thrown exceptions only at runtime
- The triggered default behavior in the case of a thrown but not specified exception is usually unusable and often misunderstood by the programmers

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the exception specifications are only good as empty exception specification. Otherwise I think they're an experiment that failed. See [phlipsy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410226/is-there-any-use-for-c-throw-decoration/1410294#1410294) why.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if the checker/compiler can do that. Perhaps it's just easier to comment it in the function declaration. Well it aint fool proof but if people see that there can be an exception thrown than most of the people will wrap the function call in try and catch.

```
//Can throw Exception
GetFoo();
```