# what does this function declaration mean in c++

Tags: c++

```
virtual const char* what() const throw()
{

}
```

AFAIK it's a function that will return a constant pointer to a mutable char. The rest I am not sure. Could anybody help?

Comment: Which part of this do you want to have explained?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Regarding the `const throw()` part:

- `const` means that this function (which is a member function) will not change the observable state of the object it is called on. The compiler enforces this by not allowing you to call non-`const` methods from this one, and by not allowing you to modify the values of members.
- `throw()` means that you promise to the compiler that this function will never allow an exception to be emitted. This is called an *exception specification*, and (long story short) is useless and possibly misleading.

Comment: An interesting look at exception specifications is [here](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm). [Larry Osterman](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2006/03/22/558390.aspx) also wrote a blog article about it, and there's a question about it here on Stack Overflow: [is there any use for C++ throw decoration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410226/is-there-any-use-for-c-throw-decoration).

Comment: Why is it declared private?

Answer (score 13):

It means that `what` is a virtual member function returning `const char*` which can be invoked on const objects(the const in the end). `throw()` means that it *sort of* guarantees not to throw anything.

check out [exception specifications in C++](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr156.htm), and note that they are deprecated in C++0x:)

Comment: +1 for the very interesting link. Didn't know this side! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

From left to right:

- `virtual` - this function may be overridden in derived classes
- `const char*` - this function returns a modifiable pointer to a constant (array of) char
- `what()` - this function takes no parameters
- `const` - this function does not modify the (non-`mutable`) members of the object on which it is called, and hence can be called on `const` instances of its class
- `throw()` - this function is not expected to throw any exceptions. If it does, `unexpected` will be called.

Answer (score 3):

virtual function returning a pointer to a non-modifiable buffer of chars, taking no arguments, does not modify any member variables of the class is belongs to (i.e. can be called on const instances), and won't throw any kind of exception.

Comment: The `throw()` decoration means that it won't throw any exceptions, not that it can throw any type.

Answer (score 2):

the function `what()` takes no parameters, returns a `pointer` to a `const char` (so you can't modify the what the pointer points to, but you can modify the pointer itself). It's `virtual`, so its behaviour can be overridden in derived classes. It won't throw exceptions. It doesn't modify any members of the class that it belongs to.

Comment: Hmm, no. The `throw()` decoration means that it won't throw any exceptions.

Comment: Yup, you're right. That's what I intended to write. No idea what I was thinking :) Thanks! Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

It's a virtual function that returns a const char*. The `const` at the end of the method means it is not allowed to change the state of the object it is called upon. Which means it is not allowed to modify any member variables of the object. `throw()` part is the exception specification that says the method doesn't throw any exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. `virtual`: This means that the function can be reimplemented in subclasses, and calls to the method via a base class pointer will end up calling the reimplementation.
2. `const char *` is not a constant pointer to a mutable char - it's the other way round.
3. `const` means that this method can even be called on const instances of this class.
4. `throw()` means that this method will not yield any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the const after the functions: there are really two
meanings, what the compiler understands, and what the usual
programming conventions make it mean.  As far as the compiler is
concerned, all it does is make the this pointer a pointer to
const.  The const can be cast away, or various indirections
used, to modify the observable state of the object.  In the end,
this const means whatever the programmer wants it to mean.

The usual convention, today, is that it means that the
observable state of the object will not change.  For some
reasonable definition of "observable state".

Concerning the exception specification: an empty exception
specification is a no throw guarantee, and is very important
when considering exception safety.  The next version of the
standard has deprecated exception specifications, but it does
provide some other means of specifying that a function will
never throw.

Answer (score 1):

1. `virtual` this one is used to overridden in derived class from base class
2. `const char*` This is a pointer to a constant character
3. `what` Returns a null-terminated character sequence that may be used to identify any exception
4. `throw()` parameter inside the throw is empty so it will call std::unexpected  for all exception

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>

class Myexception:public exception
{
    virtual const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return "My exception here";
    }
} myex;

int main()
{
    try() 
    {
        throw myex;
    }
    catch(exception &e)
    {
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually returns a *mutable* pointer to a *constant* character block.

The rest is already explained by others.

Answer (score -1):

Base class for all library exceptions.

This is the base class for all exceptions thrown by the standard library, and by certain language expressions. You are free to derive your own exception classes, or use a different hierarchy, or to throw non-class data (e.g., fundamental types).