# What is the meaning of this header (virtual const char* what() const throw())?

Tags: c++, exception

```
class myexception: public exception
{
  virtual const char* what() const throw()
  {
    return "My exception happened";
  }
};
```

Sorry, this question may sound dumb, but I have trouble parsing the header. Can someone describe in English what the header actually means? The first thing that seems odd to me is the keyword `virtual`. The `myexception` class is not a base class and inherits from the already implemented `exception` class, so why use `virtual` here? I guess `const` is for the return type which is a c-style string that is const, and the other `const` is to make sure nothing that the this object cannot be modified (can someone tell me what that object could be?). I have no idea what `throw()` does exactly, never seen this syntax before.

Comment: virtual const char* what() allows the what() method to be overridden in classes derived from myexception

Comment: This is a base class as soon as you derive another class from it.

Comment: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm

Comment: can we omit to use virtual here?

Comment: what does throw() do and generally when can you put another method in the header?

Comment: throw() says it throws no exceptions. It's not a method, it's an empty throw-list.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: 100% the opposite

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah, as I see from @EJP's comment: `throw()` without further specification effectively means nothing throwed, right?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yes... `noexcept` means `throw()`. From cppreference: "noexcept is an improved version of throw(), which is deprecated in C++11. Unlike throw(), noexcept will not call std::unexpected and may or may not unwind the stack, which potentially allows the compiler to implement noexcept without the runtime overhead of throw()."

Comment: Downvoted the irrelevant stuff, and left place for a **real** answer (just too tired/lazy myself for now) ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230463/what-does-this-function-declaration-mean-in-c

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> virtual

Adds nothing, as the method being overridden is already virtual. You are correct: it can be omitted.

> const char* what()

A member function named `what()` that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to `const char`.

> const

The member function can be called via a `const` pointer or reference to an instance of this class or a derived class.

> throw()

Throws no exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The `virtual` keyword is optional (you can skip it or explicitly write down - no difference) when you override an already virtual method from a base class (like in this case). Your remarks about the two `const` keywords are almost correct. It's basic C++.

Comment: The virtual keyword actually does a difference.

Comment: @ciamej Not in the case specified.

Comment: @EJP but, we don't know if there exists a class that derives from myexception, the code snippet might be just a small excerpt of the whole code. If so the virtual keyword is important.

Comment: Or more precisely, we don't know if there are, somewhere in the code, pointers to myexception which may point to instances of myexception subclasses

Comment: @ciamej You've missed the point completely. The method is already virtual in the base class, so adding virtual here does nothing.

Comment: but what does throw() do and generally when can you put another method in the header?

Comment: @ciamej As I said, you've missed the point completely. Several times now.

Comment: @ciamej: It makes no difference because `std::exception` already has a `what()` that is virtual. This virtualness is already being inherited. It is redundant to write it again here.