# Why bad_exception is not thrown automatically?

Tags: c++, exception

Why doesn't this piece of code run without error? Isn't `bad_exception` supposed to be called automatically when an unexpected exception is encountered? Or is it necessary to set a handler for it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
class C{};
void test() throw(bad_exception)
{
    throw C();
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
         test();
    } catch(bad_exception& e)
    {
        cout << "Caught ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In C++03 theory:**
If you throw an exception that is not in the exception specification, `unexpected()` gets called. If you have not set the unexpected handler via `set_unexpected()` this means `terminate()` gets called which is the case you observed. If you *have* set an unexpected handler that does not call terminate but throws an exception, and if that exception is not listed in your exception specification, it gets translated into bad_exception. So in order to get the expected result, call `set_unexpected()` first with an appropriate handler.

**In C++03 practice:**
Some compilers do not support exception specifications at all (other than `throw()`), others just don't evaluate/check them for correctness. As [Herb Sutter points out](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm), exception specifications create a clumsy "shadow type system" that is not easy to handle right (if it is possible at all). Therefore..

**... in C++11:** 
Exception specifications are *deprecated*. You should rather not use them. However, there is a [`nothrow`](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/using-noexcept/) operator that has a slightly different functionality than `throw()`

---

**PS: so why have std::bad_exception in C++03?**
You hav three different regions of code:

- The function you are writing an exception specification for.
- The "foreign" code you are calling from that function that might or might not throw an exception that does not match you specification.
- The (maybe also unknown) unexpected handler that can be anything and should either terminate/exit/abort the program or throw anything.

So if the "foreign" code throws an exception that violates your exception specification, you have three possible outcomes of that:

1. The handler terminates the program. There is not much you can do about that unless you set your own handler in the function.
2. The handler throws an exception that matches your exception specification. And all is well.
3. The handler throws something else. What do you want the runtime to do now? That's where bad_exception comes in: If it is in your specification, the "something else" gets translated into a bad_exception, and the program continues. If it's not, terminate gets called.

Setting your own handler inside the function disables any handler that was previously set by anyone else who just wants to use your function. He will not expect you to disable his handler. Besides, the handler is meant as a *global* what-happens-if policy and thus is nothing you should care about in a single function implementation.

Comment: So why do we need bad_exception.. We could have set a handler for unexpected exception which in turn throws something that we can catch?

Comment: `noexcept` is not the same as `throw()`.

Comment: thx for the comments - added an answer to the "why bad_exception" question and fixed the noexcept/throw() issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

This should call `std::unexpected` which by default call `std::terminate()` as the thrown exception isn't part of the exception specification.

(It does here with g++ on Linux, <strike>Sun</strike>Oracle CC on Solaris, IBM xlC on AIX BTW)

If you install an unexpected handler, it works as you expect here:

```
include <iostream>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;
class C{};

void myunexpected()
{
    throw std::bad_exception();
}

void test() throw(std::bad_exception)
{
    throw C();
}
int main()
{
    try
    {
        set_unexpected(myunexpected);
        test();
    } catch(std::bad_exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught ";
    }
}
```

Comment: This should actually call `std::unexpected`, as explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1410255/160206), which by default calls `std::terminate`.

Comment: @BjörnPollex, yes, I was imprecise. I've completed with an example of installing an unexpected handler.

Comment: So why do we need bad_exception.. We could have set a handler for unexpected exception which in turn throws something that we can catch?

Answer (score 1):

As per [except.unexpected], when a function throws an exception not listed in its dynamic exception specification, `std::unexpected()` is called. According to [unexpected.handler], the default implementation of `std::unexpected()` simply calls `std::terminate()`.

However, the program can install its own handler, which can (re-)throw an exception. If the exception thus thrown is not allowed by the dynamic exception specification, it can be replaced by `std::bad_exception` when that *is* allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your catch-block would only catch exceptions of the type `bad_exception`, or a subtype thereof. `C` does not meet this criterion.

Actually, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410226/is-there-any-use-for-c-throw-decoration) is very similar to yours. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1410255/160206) explains that if your function throws an exception that does not match the specification (if there is any), then `std::unexpected` is called, which by default calls `std::terminate`.