# Exception propagation analysis in C++

Tags: c++, exception, static-analysis

Our code has certain guidelines as to which exceptions are

- `ad-hoc` -- *function boundary* -- for handling rare error-situations within a single function, where other methods of flow control are impractical,
- `internal` -- *library boundary* -- for communicating error-situations between several components within a library,
- `external` -- *`main` boundary* -- for communicating error-situations across library-boundary, to *foreign* code.

To make sure the written library/foreign code conforms, I've done a semi-automated analysis of exception propagation, by:

1. filtering interesting `throw` statements with `grep`,
2. creating a potential call tree (with Eclipse/CDT) for each function not immediately handling the above-identified thrown exception
3. analyzing the call tree manually and checking whether the given exception is eventually handled no later than the relevant boundary

My question is, is there a static analyzer that does just this?

Answer (score 1):

I think no matter at what you look at it would be custom. Don't know if a commercial tool is an option but I believe [Klocwork](http://www.klocwork.com) might fit.

But this would involve using something they call KAST. A tool to create custom rules in an XPath type format. Pretty easy to create and powerful.

However with that said it is way overkill to use Klocwork just for this. Worth a look.

Comment: I feel this would be an overkill just from the description. And from how you put it, it sounds I'd have to get my hands real dirty in KAST just to see if it would help me or not... I mean thanks for the pointer to Klocwork, but no answer :)

Comment: KAST uses XPath. Your right, if you don't know much about XPath then don't bother.

Answer (score 0):

This seems relevant
[Exception analysis tool for C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28261/exception-analysis-tool-for-c?rq=1)

But you're interested in the catch-points for exceptions. As far as my experience goes, static analyzers will only let you know about uncaught exceptions.

Comment: I had seen the question before asking, but it didn't help. In principle, If a static analysis could tell me which exception may propagate out of every single function -- what that question asks -- I could filter that information to answer my question, but not even that is answered satisfactorily.